# How to increase Maximum Worker Process in Azure Websites?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a asp.net MVC 5 application hosted on Windows Azure websites. 
Previously it was hosted in a VPS (SoftSys hosting) and i had set up Maximum Worker Process for application pool to 2.

How do i set it in Azure website ?

I am using Basic B1 Azure Website hosting plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This level of fine-tuning is beyond the scope of an Azure Website. You'll have to opt for a WebRole and use startup script (or equivalent methods).

For an updated list of allowed `Web.Config` overrides, see:

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/01/28/more-to-explore-configuration-options-unlocked-in-windows-azure-web-sites/

Comment: Ok. I just checked the Azure portal and i see that my Website has 2 worker process already running. How come ? I thought it is one by default. Is that dependent on the plan ?

Comment: Where do you see it? In Monitoring?

Comment: If you refer to the Processes panel, the warning at the top may explain the 2nd process: `Warning : using the Process Explorer increases your website's number of HTTP requests`.

Comment: Ohh yes. You are right. So no matter what plan i am using, i can not control the WP ..is my understanding right ? The  only way to scale is to setup new instances.

Comment: Yes. I would say the *Cloudy* way to scale on Azure (being a Cloud environment) is by increasing the number of instances. Also, the number of Worker Processes are not directly related to scalability and in fact I can see it as a benefit (and not as a limitation) that it's maintained automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following command help?
*Set-AzureWebsite -name "websitename" -Slot "slot-name" -NumberOfWorkers 2*

The above works and maximum is 3 for Basic plan. Tested it today.